# Flutter Null Pointer Exception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.Display.getSize' on a null object reference

Tags: android, flutter, nullpointerexception, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Facing this error, I have searched a lot, Everyone points this to webview plugin but I am not using any webview flutter. This is working fine in Debug mode but app crashes in release mode. seeking help!!

PS: It occurs only in Android versions (5.1, 6.0, 7.0)

[Flutter Doctor:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiQbd.png)

[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0WDo.png)

> E/AndroidRuntime(18472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472): Process: com.contacts.backup.transfer.restore.zp, PID: 18472
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.Display.getSize(android.graphics.Point)' on a null object reference
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at org.chromium.ui.display.DisplayAndroid.updateFromDisplay(DisplayAndroid.java:280)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at org.chromium.ui.display.DisplayAndroidManager$DisplayListenerBackendImpl.onDisplayChanged(DisplayAndroidManager.java:176)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:786)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
> E/AndroidRuntime(18472):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)